# How to make #if preprocessor be conditional upon a values in another different file?

Tags: c++, preprocessor

For example if a "settings" file exists and has the following:

`system,ubuntu`

Can a preprocessor `#if` be used to customise the code based of the values in the settings file? For example:

`#if lookup_system == "ubuntu"  // loopup_system is pseudocode`

Another use can could be to look up whether or not the code is running on production servers.

Comment: This is only possible if the "settings" file is parsed by the build system, which adds the correct macros when building. Remember that the preprocessor is a *compile-time* only thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that.

However, you might **generate some header file** from external data. The [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf) utility does that (actually generates some `configure` script generating such a header).

More generally, you should set up your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) system (e.g. edit your `Makefile` for [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), or your `build.ninja` for [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)) to generate that header file suitably (perhaps with a tiny script, your own C++ -another- program, or whatever). You can also have a clever build system passing specific [`-D` flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) to your compiler.

Remember that **C++ files** (both header files e.g. `.hh` and implementation files e.g. `.cc` ...) **can be generated** by something else. This is common practice.

Read more about your [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor), e.g. about [`cpp`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/). It is a compile only thing. With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you can get the preprocessed form `foo.ii` of your `foo.cc` file with a command [such as](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) 
 `g++ -C -E foo.cc > foo.ii`.